# Show AdMob Native Ads with MoPub (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob, ads, mopub

I am integrating MoPub SDK to mediate ADs from the Google AdMob network. I can get the AD to show after implementing my own customEvent and Adapter, but i can't get the AD to handle click events on its own. As in when I click on the AdMob native AD, it won't direct me anywhere. When using Facebook and Flurry's CustomEvent and Adapter, clicks are handled automatically. Anyone have any experience on this subject?

Thanks in Advance. Code below:

MPGoogleAdMobCustomEvent

```
@interface MPGoogleAdMobCustomEvent()
@property(nonatomic, strong)GADAdLoader *loader;
@end

@implementation MPGoogleAdMobCustomEvent

- (void)requestAdWithCustomEventInfo:(NSDictionary *)info
{
    MPLogInfo(@"MOPUB: requesting AdMob Native Ad");

    NSString *adUnitID = [info objectForKey:@"adUnitID"];

    if (!adUnitID) {

        [self.delegate nativeCustomEvent:self didFailToLoadAdWithError:MPNativeAdNSErrorForInvalidAdServerResponse(@"MOPUB: No AdUnitID from GoogleAdMob")];

        return;
    }

    self.loader = [[GADAdLoader alloc] initWithAdUnitID:adUnitID rootViewController:nil  adTypes:@[kGADAdLoaderAdTypeNativeContent] options:nil];
    self.loader.delegate = self;
    GADRequest *request = [GADRequest request];

#if (TARGET_OS_SIMULATOR)

    request.testDevices = @[ kGADSimulatorID ];

#endif

    CLLocation *location = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init].location;
    if (location) {
        [request setLocationWithLatitude:location.coordinate.latitude
                               longitude:location.coordinate.longitude
                                accuracy:location.horizontalAccuracy];
    }
    request.requestAgent = @"MoPub";
    [self.loader loadRequest:request];
}

- (void)adLoader:(GADAdLoader *)adLoader didReceiveNativeContentAd:(GADNativeContentAd *)nativeContentAd
{
    MPLogDebug(@"MOPUB: Did receive nativeAd");

    MPGoogleAdMobNativeAdAdapter *adapter = [[MPGoogleAdMobNativeAdAdapter alloc] initWithGADNativeContentAd:nativeContentAd];
    adapter.url = nativeContentAd.advertiser;
    MPNativeAd *interfaceAd = [[MPNativeAd alloc] initWithAdAdapter:adapter];

    NSMutableArray *imageArray = [NSMutableArray array];

    for (GADNativeAdImage *images in nativeContentAd.images) {

        [imageArray addObject:images.imageURL];

    }


    [super precacheImagesWithURLs:imageArray completionBlock:^(NSArray *errors) {

        if ([errors count]) {
            [self.delegate nativeCustomEvent:self didFailToLoadAdWithError:errors[0]];
        } else {
            [self.delegate nativeCustomEvent:self didLoadAd:interfaceAd];
        }

    }];
}

- (void)adLoader:(GADAdLoader *)adLoader didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(GADRequestError *)error
{
    MPLogDebug(@"MOPUB: AdMob ad failed to load with error (customEvent): %@", error.description);
    [self.delegate nativeCustomEvent:self didFailToLoadAdWithError:error];
}

@end
```

MPGoogleAdMobNativeAdAdapter

```
@interface MPGoogleAdMobNativeAdAdapter()<GADNativeAdDelegate>
@property(nonatomic, strong)NSDictionary *properties;
@end

@implementation MPGoogleAdMobNativeAdAdapter

- (instancetype)initWithGADNativeContentAd:(GADNativeContentAd *)contentAD
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        self.contentAd = contentAD;
        self.contentAd.delegate = self;
        self.properties = [self convertAssetsToProperties:contentAD];
    }
    return self;
}

- (NSDictionary *)convertAssetsToProperties:(GADNativeContentAd *)adNative
{
    self.contentAd = adNative;
    NSMutableDictionary * dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    if (adNative.headline) {
        dictionary[kAdTitleKey] = adNative.headline;
    }
    if (adNative.body) {
        dictionary[kAdTextKey] = adNative.body;
    }
    if (adNative.images[0]) {
        dictionary[kAdMainImageKey] = ((GADNativeAdImage *)adNative.images[0]).imageURL.absoluteString;
    }
    if (adNative.callToAction) {
        dictionary[kAdCTATextKey] = adNative.callToAction;
    }
    return [dictionary copy];
}

#pragma mark MPNativeAdAdapter
- (NSTimeInterval)requiredSecondsForImpression
{
    return 0.0;
}

- (NSURL *)defaultActionURL
{
    return nil;
}

- (BOOL)enableThirdPartyClickTracking
{
    return YES;
}


- (void)willAttachToView:(UIView *)view
{
    self.contentAd.rootViewController = [self.delegate viewControllerForPresentingModalView];
}

- (void)didDetachFromView:(UIView *)view
{
    self.contentAd.rootViewController = nil;
}

#pragma mark GADNativeAdDelegate

- (void)nativeAdWillPresentScreen:(GADNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeAdWillPresentModalForAdapter:)]) {
        [self.delegate nativeAdWillPresentModalForAdapter:self];
    }
}

- (void)nativeAdDidDismissScreen:(GADNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeAdDidDismissModalForAdapter:)]) {
        [self.delegate nativeAdDidDismissModalForAdapter:self];
    }
}

- (void)nativeAdWillLeaveApplication:(GADNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    if ([self.delegate respondsToSelector:@selector(nativeAdWillLeaveApplicationFromAdapter:)]) {
        [self.delegate nativeAdWillLeaveApplicationFromAdapter:self];
    }
}

@end




`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are having your custom UI for AdMob Ad's, then there will be a button which you will be using for `callToAction` part.

First of all you need to add a selector to detect action of click, to do add the selector for that button

```
[callToActionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(adCalled:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

After that implement the adCalled method to get the click & call the method further, below is the code for your reference
Below is the example which I have used to get the ad object from my collection view & then I am redirecting it.

```
- (void)adCalled:(id)sender
{
    CGPoint buttonPosition = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:mainCollectionView];   // Get the button position
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [collectionView indexPathForItemAtPoint:buttonPosition];    // Get the index path of button so that I can retrieve the correct ad object
    id selectedAd = [adArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    if ([selectedAd isKindOfClass:[GADNativeContentAd class]]) {
        NSString *url = [selectedAd valueForKey:@"googleClickTrackingURLString"];
        NSLog(@"URL is :%@", url);
        NSURL *googleUrl = [NSURL URLWithString:url];
        if ([[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL: googleUrl]) {
            [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:googleUrl];
        }
    }
}
```

Using this I can open the link n web using the google tracking url.

Hope this helps.